# Python script embedded in HTML

Tags: python, html

I've seen many questions that ask similar things, but I felt none of them asked it in this particular way.  I have a Python script that asks for an input number and attempts to calculate another number based on some variables.  It's very simple, but I would love to be able to run it from an HTML link.  Is there a way to do this with straight HTML?  The Python code is:

```
Q = 'y'
while (Q != 'n'):
      B = 3.512929      
      S = input("Number? ")      
      F = S/B
      if (S > 200):
            F = F - 50
            S = S - 200      
      for i in range(int(F),int((F*2)+1)):
            four = float(S/i - 0.1)
            if (four < B and four > 1.5):
                  if (i%5 == 0):
                      print ("The second number might be " + str(i))
                      print ("")
      Q = raw_input("Continue?(y/n) ")
```

When the script is run, the command prompt asks what the number is and then displays the possible second numbers if they're divisible by 5.  It's very nice and simple.  In fact, the only real Pythonic code is the range(int,int).  I think it could probably be written in PHP or even Javascript, but I don't know how...I just want to have it run from an HTML page.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You can do this in Python the same ways you could in PHP—that is, with server-side support, either CGI or `mod_python` embedded code. But there are better ways to write server-side code in Python than CGI. Is that what you want?

Comment: Alternatively, if you want this to be pure client-side code, unless you can rely on people installing a funky custom plug-in in their browsers, you either need a (partial) Python interpreter running JS, or a (partial) Python-to-JS compiler, or a Python interpreter running in Java or Flash or something else that can run in a web page. Is one of those what you want?

Comment: http://www.skulpt.org/# is one way to do it ...

Comment: @abarnert Sounds like Javascript is what I should probably use.  I didn't really plan on dozens of users (more like four or five), but with so many decisions, it makes sense to pick one and go with it.  Plus, learning Javascript would certainly help down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with "straight HTML". HTML is just a layout language; it has almost no functionality for what you're trying to do. You need some kind of scripting language.

While there are browser plugins for embedding Python directly as a scripting language, most of your users won't have such a plugin installed; you may not even be able to find an up-to-date one for your own browser. In fact, what you're going to have available is:

- JavaScript (or, if you want to get technical, "ECMAscript") in almost all browsers.
- Flash/ActionScript in many browsers.
- Silverlight in some browsers.
- Java in a few browsers (until recently, it was much more common).

Silverlight actually *does* let you run (Iron)Python code, although it's still going to be some work to translate your code from the command-line Python environment to the browser-scripting Silverlight environment. Likewise, Java lets you run Jython code. The other two require porting your code to another language. And no one is going to do that for you; you'll need to learn JavaScript yourself.

---

Except… some Python programs can actually be *automatically translated* to JavaScript/etc. by tools like [`pyjs`](http://pyjs.org). I'm not recommending that one in particular; there are many of them, all with different limitations, and it's up to you to search and find one that you like.

Also, keep in mind that web apps are inherently *graphical*, not command-line-based. You (or some tool) will have to convert all that `input` and `print` code into something reasonable.

---

Alternatively, there are (partial) Python interpreters written in JavaScript, etc., like [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org). Again, not a recommendation for a particular tool; search the options and figure out which one you want.

Anyway, this way, your web page is running a Python interpreter, which is running your Python script. Some of them can even simulate command-line I/O just fine.

---

Finally, you can put your Python code on a server, and talk to it with plain HTML forms and/or JavaScript on the client side.

You can do this the exact same ways you would with PHP—either as a CGI script, or as embedded `mod_python` code. But there are better alternatives for Python than either of those.

You can also use frameworks that can both help make the server-side Python code simpler, and also automatically generate the client-side HTML/JS automatically for you, so you only have to worry about the Python code.